# Ionic v1 build issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-v1

Hope everything is fine.

I have an old ionic v1 project.

The project was using sms features.

however after google update:

I received

> Issue: Violation of the Permissions policy

We only allow apps to access Call Log or SMS data for permitted uses and only to enable the app’s core functionality

Google has removed my app.

I need to rebuild it again after fixing the issue.

Now we have ionic v 4.1.0.

My project structure is missed up.

The earlier developer, was using cord-ova, ionic,phone gap... etc

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was finding myself in a similar situation. The best and fastest way in this case would be to start a new project while you have the other one open and try to copy as much code as you can. I hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: I suggested this to my collegue. He said wasting og time. But I will try.

Comment: do I need a new keystore.